# trouble about image slider html CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, slider

dudes.
have made my image slider, but the first click doesn’t trigger an animation. It just jumps to the target. I want to smoothly changing of picture, but the firs just jump.
To understand my question better, go to 
http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/#slider-image-3 and pay attention to animation between images.

here is html-code:

```
<div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is CSS:

```
 .slider-holder
    {
        width: 800px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .image-holder
    {
        width: 2400px;
        background-color: red;
        height: 400px;
        clear: both;
        position: relative;

        -webkit-transition: left 2s;
        -moz-transition: left 2s;
        -o-transition: left 2s;
        transition: left 2s;
    }

    .slider-image
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -800px;
    }

    #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -1600px;
    }

    .button-holder
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
    }

    .slider-change
    {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: brown;
    }
```

Is there a way to fix that? 
Than for all of you for helping me.

Comment: Hi, please update your html to have real images instead of local paths. If somebody wants to help you they don't have to do it themself, or just update the question using different background colors

Answer (score 1):

Change this bit:

```
 #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder {
    left: 0px;
}
```

to

```
 #slider-image-1 ~ .image-holder {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much I have learn new thing. Otherwise I will achieve by this way <script type="text/javascript">window.location.hash = '#slider-image-1'</script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is given image width and second image width added. you check your image width and change as per your images. Given demo is working correct

Comment: #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: 0px;
    }
    #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -800px;
    }
    #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -1600px;
    }